# How to enable FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING using jersey 2.0 and servlet 3.0 without a web.xml?

Tags: java, jackson, servlet-3.0, jersey-2.0

I want to use the @JsonAnySetter feature to collecut unknowns when receiving JSON, so I added the annotated method to my class (which is annotated with @XmlRootElement) and

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

to my web.xml.  This works fine.

I decided to try and get rid of my web.xml.

I changed my class to

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class ListingRS extends ResourceConfig {

    public ListingRS() {
        packages("com.onlineimage.totalproperties");
    }
```

and everything works except the @JsonAnySetter is never called.

I tried to add getFeatures() as I found in an example

```
public ListingRS() {
    packages("com.onlineimage.totalproperties");
    getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
}
```

but getFeatures() is not recognized and I think it's Jersey 1.x?

I changed it to

```
public ListingRS() {
    packages("com.onlineimage.totalproperties");
    getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
}
```

but I dont have an import for JSONConfiguration and I cant figure out what to import with Jersey 2.0.  Also I'm not sure that getProperties() is the correct way to do this.

for my Gradle libraries I'm using

```
List compileLibraries =['org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.0',
                        'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.0']
```

The root of the issue is, I want to use @XmlRootElement on my class for the easy xml converting and @JsonAnySetter to handle unknowns.
The @JsonAnySetter method is never called if I don't enable JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING.

Assuming I'm not doing something horribly wrong in the above, how to I enable JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING without the web.xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18074743/1296150  This answer from @michal.gajdos to another of my questions should also make this work.