# REST post request

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0

when i try to send message on the server response is: Unsupported media type. (415)

```
{
    "street": "Alex",
    "picture": "fsdfs"
}
```

I use Jersey 2.7. It is okey when I call GET, but the problem is with the POST method. 
Into the project I included org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson and il\ncluded code like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068176/what-is-the-moxy-equivalent-to-jacksons-jsonanysetter/18074743#18074743)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, RuntimeException {
        final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("org.template")
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);

        server = new Server(PORT_NUMBER);
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }
```

Simple API:

```
     @Path("/test")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public class ExampleAPI {

            @GET
            @Path("hello")
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            public String hello() {
                return "Hello World";
            }

            @POST
            @Path("/create")
    public Response create(BeanInfo bean) {

        return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(BeanInfo.class)
                .path("{picture}").build(bean.getPicture()))
                .entity(bean.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? Should I map objects to json?

BeanInfo:

```
    @JsonProperty("picture")
    private final String picture;

    @JsonProperty("street")
    private final String street;
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're incorrectly setting the Content-Type header when you're calling your service. You must set it to "application/json". To my mind, your server-side is correctly defined and the problem sits on your client side and how it is calling the API.

> 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the
>     origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload
>     is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
>     The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
>     Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the
>     data directly.

Comment: Okay, but you have to correctly configure it. I use Postman to test  my APIs too so have a look at this image to see how to properly configure it (pay attention to the "Header" part) --> [Image at TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/r/2dsqtg1/8)

Comment: The problem was with bean class.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will vote up when I will reach 15+ reputation

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with bean class. I used builder pattern and Jackson wasn't able to decode it. 
I added annotation to class and builder and now works fine.

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = BeanInfo.Builder.class)
public class BeanInfo{ ...
```

and for builder:

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "set")
public static class Builder {...
```